# Excel MATCH range without specific CELL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, cell, string-matching

after a deep search on the internet i gave up.

My "simple" question would be:
*How can I add two ranges in a formula, preferably in MATCH?*

I want to search a range like A1:A7 + A9:A20 and thus **not** include A8 in my range.

Is this possible? Please help me out

Comment: Not tried with `Match()`, but the official Union operator is `,`. So it should be `A1:A7, A9:A20`

Comment: @PatrickHonorez The official union operator is a comma in Excel? Commas are used in Excel to separate arguments in a function, not to concatenate arrays?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 of course it is. Try writing  `=SUM(F2:F4, S2:S4)`. Web is full of examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union  or http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/16/union-and-intersect/

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Ah, I wasn't aware that comma was called union operator in certain Excel functions. `MATCH` is not one of these. [This question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/447492/is-there-a-union-operator-in-excel) cleared it up.

Comment: JvdV has provided a good answer in the case of excluding one specific cell within a continuous single column/row range but I think maybe it is simpler to just use two **MATCH** function for each range without the need of using array formulas.

Comment: @TerryW, true that. Included in my answer now :)

Comment: Would you be comfortable in adding everything `A1:A20` then subtract `A8` afterwards?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio the values in A1:A20 are not numbers but formulas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Natively you can't but you could try to bypass it with either:

---

***Exclude a single cell:***

If you want to exclude a certain cell from a `MATCH` you can exclude it's certain row number like so:

```
=MATCH(1,(A1:A20="X")*(ROW(A1:A20)<>8),0)
```

Or

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX((A1:A20="X")*(ROW(A1:A20)<>8),),0)
```

Both are array formulas but only the first one needs to be confirmed by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

***Exclude a range of cells:***

If you would want to exclude a range of rows, e.g. 8-12, then we cannot use the `AND` or `OR` logic as they don't return an array. However, we can mimic it ourselves like:

```
=MATCH(1,(A1:A20="x")*((ROW(A1:A20)<8)+(ROW(A1:A20)>12)),0)
```

Or

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX((A1:A20="x")*((ROW(A1:A20)<8)+(ROW(A1:A20)>12)),),0)
```

Where, again, both are array formulas but only the first one needs to be confirmed by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

***Alternative***

Alternatively, you could stack `MATCH` functions in a number of ways, but here is one of them:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("x",A1:A7,0),MATCH("x",A13:A20,0))
```

- Pro: No array formula > Fast!
- Con: Will return a match's relative row position in either the first or second range. In this example you could just add 12 to the second result.

Good luck =)

Comment: Array within Match, very nice, I always default to SUMPRODUCT on this but your way is cleaner and shorter.

Comment: Technically this doesn't answer the question. This answers "how to find a `MATCH` excluding a certain row?" instead of "how to find a `MATCH` of two concatenated arrays?" but... maybe this is what the OP wants. I guess we will find out. Still a good answer. +1

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889, I understand where you comming from, but the title states "...without specific cell". I also don't see where OP concatenates two ranges, rather than trying to exclude `A8`, being that one cell. Thanks for the kudo's :)

Comment: Thank you all for your fast and reliable answers... will check it out tommorrow and report back to you what worked for my situation- Thanks in advance

Comment: @JvdV honestly it would interest my how two concatenated ranges work as well but as for my current issue i only need a single colum range without a specific cell... nonetheless i am grateful for both answers and will try them respectfully out

Comment: Somehow these formulas interfered with my ISNUMBER and didn't work out. I tried it with two MATCHes. idk why i didn't think of that before, and it seemed to work out. Thank you all for your hard work

Comment: @JayJay, I have edited the answer to accomodate your question on how to exclude a certain range of cells, or in other words "concatenate" two ranges.

Comment: Could you please explain how `(A1:A20="X")*(ROW(A1:A20)<>8)` works?